# Servidor Rest - Matriz/Filial

Tags: banco-de-dados, rest

Tenho um servidor rest que me traz as requisições da empresa matriz, agora o cliente abriu uma filial. Como faço pra que o rest se conecte no banco da filial quando o usuário fizer login no desktop local. Meu server rest fica online na matriz em outra cidade. No caso preciso trabalhar com dois bancos de dados, alguém tem alguma sugestão de como posso fazer isso?

Comment: O idioma daqui é o **português**. Traduza sua pergunta.

Comment: É pra traduzir a pergunta acima. Clique em EDITAR e traduza o texto.